# Linking Qt in CodeLite

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not sure why this is, but 99% of the problems I have with programming in C++ have to do with the gcc linker.

I want to link the Qt library to a project in CodeLite. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get the error

```
/Users/andrew/Dev/C++/COSC 102/elitecod/main.cpp:1:24: error: QApplication: No such file or directory
```

I have Qt installed (with Homebrew, Mac OS X Lion) in `/usr/local/include`. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Note this a compiler error it has not started the linker at all

Comment: I'm not quite sure ( this is why I ain't propose it as an answer ) but is the compiler lookin in /usr/local/include natively? Maybe try to add the path where the header lies to your include paths? And is the header just written into the "include" directory? Shouldnt there be some kind of subdirectory like "QT" ?

Comment: OHH! I was putting the include path in the Libraries text box under Linker instead of the Include Path box under Compiler!

Comment: Sadly, this didn't fix it. This is so pointless it's not even worth trying to learn C++. Back to Python!

Comment: [I had some snarky reply about using Qt Creator or Linux or something, but decided against it.] C and C++ can be a bit difficult before you realize how include paths and library paths work, then you get to deployment where your users don't even have nearly the same versions but rather something 5 years old. Then you will learn to include the libraries with your application and hoping for the best.

Comment: Qt Creator is great, but I'm also looking for information about linking in general so I can use GMP, FFTW, sndfilelib, etc. I've also failed to compile my programs with `make` and `gcc` under Linux, so my knowledge is the problem here. However, including libraries would actually be much better than linking. What's the proper term there, "including" in a binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates it can't find the file QApplication. You need to add the Qt 'include' directory to the list of places the compiler should look for it and other header files.

A brief google seems to indicate you may have other problems with Qt, you might want to keep [this](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/QmakePlugin) link handy.